# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() blocks

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am trying to retrieve the Google Plus access token for a signed in user in my Android application. I am doing this using the following code, which follows suggestions made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547019/calling-this-from-your-main-thread-can-lead-to-deadlock-and-or-anrs-while-getti/17547891#17547891), [here](https://gist.github.com/ianbarber/9607551) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371157/message-needpermission-when-get-token-code):

```
private class RetrieveTokenTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH = 466453; // Any number, not really using it anyway.
        String accountName = params[0];
        String scopes = "oauth2:" + Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN;
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getActivity(), accountName, scopes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return token;
    }
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mSignInClicked = false;

    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

    try {
        String accessToken = (new RetrieveTokenTask()).execute(Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient)).get();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have the following permissions in my AndroidManifest (among others):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

The problem is that when calling `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`, there is no progress being made and it will just freeze there. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that when calling GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(), there is
>   no progress being made and it will just freeze there.

Because you are calling `get()` method `AsyncTask` which make Main UI Thread wait until `doInBackground` computation not completed

> How can I fix this?

Execute `AsyncTask` by calling  `execute` method and use [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) to get `accessToken`

Comment: This is just a quick try to ensure that the token retrieval works fine. I will update that after I fix this, but the real question is why does the getToken() method not make any progress?

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki: First remove `get()` method then check it

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki: and also make sure INTERNET permission is also available

Comment: Ok, that fixed it .. Wasn't expecting that. If you could please detail your answer a bit on why this is happening I will award it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki: my answer is already in detail. application is freezing because when we call get method of  `AsyncTask` then system block control until doInBackground computation not completed but with out `get` method `doInBackground` run in background thread without blocking execution of main ui Thread and when `doInBackground` method execution completed system call `onPostExecute ` method to inform main ui thread about `doInBackground` method execution is completed. for more details see [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)